# why datastax cassandra community ami has opscenter

Tags: amazon-ami, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I just launched a datastax cassandra ami.

Noticed that the opscenter is by default running.

1. Do I have to disable the opscenter for each of the ami I launched?
2. What linux command to ensure opscenter won't run as a service?

Ultimately I want to run opscenter on my local server, remotely connecting to the cluster in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMILaunch.html

instance can be configured

--opscenter [no]    Optional. By default, DataStax OpsCenter is installed on the first instance. Specify no to disable.

Sorry guys, I should have read the documents more carefully.